# AngularJS: link method's scope varaible is empty in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to get message from `$scope.array` to be displayed in angularjs popup. It's not working:  in link method message value is properly found but message value is empty in template. Why?

My directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.directive('formFieldInformation',function(){

        var myController = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.message = 'aaaa';

        $scope.messages = [];
        $scope.messages['userNameField'] = "userName Field";
        $scope.messages['userNameSection'] = "userName Section";
        }];


        return{
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"  style="font-size: 18px; max-width:10px; padding-top:0.6em;"  uib-popover="{{message}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="true"></i>',
        scope: {
            message: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.fieldName = attrs.fieldname;
            scope.message = scope.messages[attrs.fieldname];
            console.log('message for display: '+scope.message);
        },
        controller: myController
        //replace: true
    };
});
```

usage of directive:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
    <form-field-information fieldname='userNameField' ></form-field-information>
</div>
```

Comment: You defined message in scope directive, this override message value on $scope controller. And You didn't set message in your dom element. So message is empty

Comment: Remove message from scope, or set it like : 
<form-field-information fieldname='userNameField' message="bindedVar"></form-field-information>

Comment: $scope.messages['userNameField'] > that not work on array, just abject. is there any ng-repeat on messages?